# Error while trying to require_once a file

Tags: php, backend, require

I'm getting this error when I run the script:

```
Warning: require_once(..\ksUtils.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Prog\xampp\htdocs\projs\MccoS\backEnd\db\dbFunctions.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '..\ksUtils.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Prog\xampp\htdocs\projs\MccoS\backEnd\db\dbFunctions.php on line 5
```

The file that I'm requiring is in "`D:\Prog\xampp\htdocs\projs\MccoS\backEnd\db\`"

The first lines of my current script:

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

require_once '..\backEnd\db\dbFunctions.php';
```

The problem is that the file that I'm requiring (dbFunctions.php) also has a required file (ksUtils.php) and this is the cause of the error.

In dbFunctions.php I have this: `require_once '..\ksUtils.php';`

**Note: I tried to put `http://localhost/projs/MccoS/backEnd/db/dbFunctions.php` and it didn't throw an error.**

Here is my hierarchy:

```
D:\Prog\xampp\htdocs\projs\

    MccoS
    -backEnd
    --db
    ---dbFunctions.php
    --ksUtils.php
    -frontEnd
    --register.php
```

How can I solve this?

**Note: I'm on Windows.**

Comment: You should have a `BASE_PATH` constant (or a similar name) that holds the absolute path to your project directory and stop working with relative pathes all over the place because this - as you can see - becomes messy. Then you can just work with require_once BASE_PATH . 'backEnd/ksUtils.php' and your problem vanishes

Comment: @Xatenev thanks for your suggestion, i've picked it and solved my problem

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

include __DIR__ . "../backEnd/db/dbFunctions.php";
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't add comment because of less reputation,as the error say,could not find the file so the problem is in definning the file path :

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

require_once="../backEnd/db/dbFunctions.php";
```

Comment: I am not sure what kind of construct `require_once="....";` is. Aswell your answer doesn't answer the problem of the OP, the require of dbFunctions.php works properly. Re-read the question.